# Consume a web service in R

Tags: r, webservice-client

Here's the scenario:

I have JBoss serving a web service with JBossWS providing me with a wsdl.  I have connected and used it from both .NET and Java so far (and it has been quite easy once I figured it out).  I am now trying to do the same with R.

Is there anything out there considered to be "the right way" for doing this?  I am not that familiar with R, and my searches have not turned up much, so I figured I'd ask and maybe spare my head and the wall a bit of damage.

Answer (score 5):

I have had good luck using rJava to recreate in R something that works in Java. I use this method for connecting to Amazon's AWS Java SDK for their API with R. This allows me, for example, to [transfer files to/from S3](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2010/11/controlling-amazon-web-services-using-rjava-and-the-aws-java-sdk/) from R without having to recreate the whole connection/handshake/boogieWoogie from R.

If you wanted to go more "pure R" I think you'll have to use some combination of [RCurl](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/) and the [XML package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) to grab and parse the wsdl.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways:

- You could retain your Java approach and use the [rJava](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rJava) package around it
- You could use [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RCurl) which is used to power a few higher-level packages (accessing Google APIs, say)
- I believe there is an older [SSOAP](http://www.omegahat.org/SSOAP/) package on [Omegahat](http://www.omegahat.org) which may help too.